# How to update the values in the array when changing language nuxt i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I am finding difficulty updating the values in the array of objects for nuxt i18n. How I can update the message in the validation array when the language got changed?

I found solutions to update single properties by moving them to the computed method but what to do with the array of objects?

```js
//Template

<div v-for="validation in validations">
    <v-alert type="danger">{{validations.message}} </v-alert>
<div>

//component
data() {

        validations: []

    },

methods() {

        submit() {

            //pushing validations array on submit method
            this.validations.push('part', message: this.$t('error.required'));

            this.validations.push('part', message: this.$t('error.mandatory'));

        }
}
```

en.json

```
error:{
required:"required en",
mandatory:"mandatory en"
}
```

fr.json

```
error:{
required:"required fr",
mandatory:"mandatory fr"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? When you toggle a locale, you should be moving from one to another. Not pushing anything specific, because those should be already populated upfront.

Comment: yes when I change the language it should refer to the key in en.json or fr.json

Comment: so basically I hit submit one time only and the error will be displayed afterward but now if I change language it should change the error message...